# WCF - How to use Windows Authenication while not being connected to the domain

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication

I have some WCF services that we secure via windows authentication.  While connected to the domain I can supply the user name and password and validate, and if i supply the wrong password I fail authentication.

How do I keep the same security while not connected to the domain?  For example a mobile device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use Windows authentication in WCF, your client doesn't have to join a domain.

You can provide username/password/domain while calling your service and it will work.

Windows authentication generally uses Kerberos or NTLM authentication protocols. Web service framework you use on the mobile device should support these protocols. I think this is the key point.